# I am having a Database or csv file and i have to export that to SharePoint Document Library can it be achieved by Powershell

Tags: document-library, powershell, search, document, csv

Is there any automated way to create SharePoint Document Library with the data's present in Database or CSV files. In that DB Table there is one column as link with Documents in it , will have to import that too.

Answer (score 1):

No direct automate way until you write your custom utility which automates the same. Below would be preferred way to do it.

Write a custom .net utility. You can read Database or CSV. For database you can use ado.net. For CSV file you can use simple .net object to read file in stream reader.

Assuming your CSV file or Database has links/path to actual documents.
In below method filePath needs to be a valid network or local path with documents. This path will come from your database/csv....below method will be called for each row in database or csv file....

```
 public Boolean UploadDocument(String fileName, String filePath, List metaDataList)   
    {  
        SP.ClientContext ctx = new SP.ClientContext(“http: //yoursharepointURL”);  
        Web web = ctx.Web;  
        FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();  
        newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);  
        newFile.Url = “ / ” + fileName;  
        List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(“Shared Documents”);  
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);  
        context.Load(uploadFile);  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
        SPClient.ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;  
        //Set the metadata  
        string docTitle = string.Empty;  
        item[“Title”] = docTitle;  
        item.Update();  
        context.ExecuteQuery();  
    }
```

Comment: I will work on this and provide an update